# Automatically delete documents based on a condition mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ttl, database-indexes

I have a database with `users` collection which contains a `verified` field in its schema. I want users that have not been verified 5min after account creation to be deleted. How can I do this?

I am already familiar with the `expires` option, but I am not sure how I can apply it conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a field `expireAt` with an [index](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index) and use [`expireAfterSeconds`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-specified-number-of-seconds) and [`partialFilterExpression`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/index-partial/) options:

```
...
verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
expireAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
  index: {
    expireAfterSeconds: 300,
    partialFilterExpression: { verified: false }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [partialFilterExpression](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/index-partial/).

```
db.users.createIndex(
  {"createdDate": 1}, 
  {expireAfterSeconds: 300, partialFilterExpression: {verified: false}}
);
```